# Why does Stripe CLI testing fail with dj-stripe?

Tags: django, stripe-payments, webhooks

I am trying to verify that the URLs work for DJ Stripe with the Stripe CLI. Originally I was going to implement the view on my own but then I decided to go with DJ Stripe. In my original view the CLI works just file listening on my URL and running `stripe trigger checkout.session.completed`:

```
✗ stripe listen --forward-to localhost:80/webhook/subscriptions
/
⡿ Checking for new versions... A newer version of the Stripe CLI is available, please update to: v1.7.4
⢿ Getting ready... > Ready! Your webhook signing secret is whsec_flxws0UD9fzx16CMB5krTZdzy5LI63SE (^C to quit)
2021-10-11 14:29:56   --> payment_intent.created [evt_3JjUC8KxszORsacj0V7a7Kll]
2021-10-11 14:29:56  <--  [200] POST http://localhost:80/webhook/subscriptions/ [evt_3JjUC8KxszORsacj0V7a7Kll]
2021-10-11 14:29:59   --> customer.created [evt_1JjUCBKxszORsacjAxsANDCu]
2021-10-11 14:29:59  <--  [200] POST http://localhost:80/webhook/subscriptions/ [evt_1JjUCBKxszORsacjAxsANDCu]
2021-10-11 14:29:59   --> payment_intent.succeeded [evt_3JjUC8KxszORsacj0ZPYDcwj]
2021-10-11 14:29:59  <--  [200] POST http://localhost:80/webhook/subscriptions/ [evt_3JjUC8KxszORsacj0ZPYDcwj]
2021-10-11 14:29:59   --> charge.succeeded [evt_3JjUC8KxszORsacj001d3jMs]
2021-10-11 14:30:00   --> checkout.session.completed [evt_1JjUCBKxszORsacjedLR1580]
2021-10-11 14:30:00  <--  [200] POST http://localhost:80/webhook/subscriptions/ [evt_3JjUC8KxszORsacj001d3jMs]
2021-10-11 14:30:00  <--  [200] POST http://localhost:80/webhook/subscriptions/ [evt_1JjUCBKxszORsacjedLR1580]
```

My working non-dj-stripe code is as follows:

```
@csrf_exempt
def stripe_subscription_webhook_received(request):

    stripe.api_key = cmu.get_stripe_api_key()
    webhook_secret = request.headers['STRIPE_SIGNATURE']
    payload = json.loads(request.body)

    try:
        event = stripe.Event.construct_from(payload, stripe.api_key)
    except ValueError as e:
        return HttpResponse(status=400)

    if event.type == 'checkout.session.completed':
        payment_intent = event.data.object
        print(payment_intent)
    elif event.type == 'invoice.paid':
        # bunch of events... 
        # ...
    else:
        print(f"Unhandled Stripe event type: {event.type}")
        cmu.email_self_about_stripe_webhook(event)

    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

However, when trying to utilize the DJ Stripe URL I am getting 400 errors:

```
✗ stripe listen --forward-to localhost:80/stripe/my_product_webhook/
⡿ Checking for new versions... A newer version of the Stripe CLI is available, please update to: v1.7.4
⣻ Getting ready... > Ready! Your webhook signing secret is whsec_flxws0UD9fzx16CMB5krTZdzy5LI63SE (^C to quit)
2021-10-11 14:37:16   --> payment_intent.created [evt_3JjUJDKxszORsacj1newBYzm]
2021-10-11 14:37:16  <--  [400] POST http://localhost:80/stripe/my_product_webhook/ [evt_3JjUJDKxszORsacj1newBYzm]
2021-10-11 14:37:21   --> customer.created [evt_1JjUJIKxszORsacjp6CsOLt1]
2021-10-11 14:37:21  <--  [400] POST http://localhost:80/stripe/my_product_webhook/ [evt_1JjUJIKxszORsacjp6CsOLt1]
2021-10-11 14:37:21   --> payment_intent.succeeded [evt_3JjUJDKxszORsacj1swQx4Mu]
2021-10-11 14:37:21   --> charge.succeeded [evt_3JjUJDKxszORsacj13CHPHjY]
2021-10-11 14:37:21  <--  [400] POST http://localhost:80/stripe/my_product_webhook/ [evt_3JjUJDKxszORsacj1swQx4Mu]
2021-10-11 14:37:21  <--  [400] POST http://localhost:80/stripe/my_product_webhook/ [evt_3JjUJDKxszORsacj13CHPHjY]
2021-10-11 14:37:21   --> checkout.session.completed [evt_1JjUJJKxszORsacjrFkPSeX2]
2021-10-11 14:37:21  <--  [400] POST http://localhost:80/stripe/my_product_webhook/ [evt_1JjUJJKxszORsacjrFkPSeX2]
```

Looking at the [dj-stripe views.py](https://github.com/dj-stripe/dj-stripe/blob/master/djstripe/views.py) source code it looks like this might be by design to return 400 errors given the `return HttpResponseBadRequest()`.

```
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name="dispatch")
class ProcessWebhookView(View):
    """
    A Stripe Webhook handler view.
    This will create a WebhookEventTrigger instance, verify it,
    then attempt to process it.
    If the webhook cannot be verified, returns HTTP 400.
    If an exception happens during processing, returns HTTP 500.
    """

    def post(self, request):
        if "HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE" not in request.META:
            # Do not even attempt to process/store the event if there is
            # no signature in the headers so we avoid overfilling the db.
            return HttpResponseBadRequest()

        trigger = WebhookEventTrigger.from_request(request)

        if trigger.is_test_event:
            # Since we don't do signature verification, we have to skip trigger.valid
            return HttpResponse("Test webhook successfully received!")

        if not trigger.valid:
            # Webhook Event did not validate, return 400
            return HttpResponseBadRequest()

        return HttpResponse(str(trigger.id))
```

My goal here is to move from my own webhook implementation to using the built in webhook and triggers in dj-stripe. But before I begin this migration I'd like to verify that the webhook endpoint is indeed working. Am I missing something here on how to get the Stripe CLI to play nicely with the dj-stripe URLs? In my settings.py I have `DJSTRIPE_WEBHOOK_URL = "my_product_webhook/"` just to make the URL more explicit. One thing that is bothering me is that my URL when looking at the DEBUG output seems to have a space in it: `stripe/ my_product_webhook/ [name='webhook']` . Seeing as I am following the [dj-stripe installation docs](https://dj-stripe.readthedocs.io/en/master/installation/) I am not clear on why this URL would have a space in it after adding `path("stripe/", include("djstripe.urls", namespace="djstripe")),` to my urls.py.

Edit: Logs for 400 errors:

```
django_web_1  | 2021-10-11 19:37:16,880 WARNING [django.request:224] log 1 281473210016224 Bad Request: /stripe/my_product_webhook/
django_web_1  | 172.23.0.4:49160 - - [11/Oct/2021:19:37:16] "POST /stripe/my_product_webhook/" 400 -
nginx_1       | 172.23.0.1 - - [11/Oct/2021:19:37:16 +0000] "POST /stripe/my_product_webhook/ HTTP/1.1" 400 0 "-" "Stripe/1.0 (+https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks)"
django_web_1  | 2021-10-11 19:37:21,199 WARNING [django.request:224] log 1 281473210016224 Bad Request: /stripe/my_product_webhook/
django_web_1  | 172.23.0.4:49162 - - [11/Oct/2021:19:37:21] "POST /stripe/my_product_webhook/" 400 -
nginx_1       | 172.23.0.1 - - [11/Oct/2021:19:37:21 +0000] "POST /stripe/my_product_webhook/ HTTP/1.1" 400 0 "-" "Stripe/1.0 (+https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks)"
django_web_1  | 2021-10-11 19:37:21,344 WARNING [django.request:224] log 1 281473210016224 Bad Request: /stripe/my_product_webhook/
django_web_1  | 172.23.0.4:49164 - - [11/Oct/2021:19:37:21] "POST /stripe/my_product_webhook/" 400 -
nginx_1       | 172.23.0.1 - - [11/Oct/2021:19:37:21 +0000] "POST /stripe/my_product_webhook/ HTTP/1.1" 400 0 "-" "Stripe/1.0 (+https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks)"
django_web_1  | 2021-10-11 19:37:21,458 WARNING [django.request:224] log 1 281473210016224 Bad Request: /stripe/my_product_webhook/
django_web_1  | 172.23.0.4:49170 - - [11/Oct/2021:19:37:21] "POST /stripe/my_product_webhook/" 400 -
nginx_1       | 172.23.0.1 - - [11/Oct/2021:19:37:21 +0000] "POST /stripe/my_product_webhook/ HTTP/1.1" 400 0 "-" "Stripe/1.0 (+https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks)"
django_web_1  | 2021-10-11 19:37:21,629 WARNING [django.request:224] log 1 281473210016224 Bad Request: /stripe/my_product_webhook/
nginx_1       | 172.23.0.1 - - [11/Oct/2021:19:37:21 +0000] "POST /stripe/my_product_webhook/ HTTP/1.1" 400 0 "-" "Stripe/1.0 (+https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks)"
django_web_1  | 172.23.0.4:49172 - - [11/Oct/2021:19:37:21] "POST /stripe/my_product_webhook/" 400 -
```

Comment: What are you seeing in your logs? I assume you're getting some error message there that may be useful

Comment: I don't think they're super useful? I've added them at the end. I can see about turning on verbose logging but presumably the dj-stripe code does not like the testing API because it is lacking some stripe signature would be my guess

Comment: Yeah, I'm not seeing anything useful there either - do you see anything from verbose logs?

Answer (score 2):

1. I think you need to make sure the signing is correct, you need to go to the `dashboard > developers > webhook > choose the hosted endpoint > then on signing secret click reveal`. It should start with `whsec...` then make sure the `DJSTRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET` is the same.
2. if that doesn't work you can check the event log, and it may tell you what's the cause error 400. Because before it goes to your implementation, it will check whether the webhook is valid or not. You can check on the event on one of djstripe models (forgot which one).